# Software enabling GLS estimation with both heteroskedasticity and serial correlation correction

Tags: regression

Does anyone know such? I tried to find such procedures in Gretl, but there you can use either hsk procedure for heteroskedasticity correction or ar1 procedure for serial correlation correction. I need the GLS procedure that will deal with both. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Function `gls()` in package **nlme** for [R](http://www.r-project.org) can handle both situations. The serial correlation is specified via argument `correlation` and heteroskedasticity is specified via the `weights` argument.

Both can take a number of pre-specified functions also provided by the package which can estimate any parameters required. For example, the serial correlation can be specified using `corAR1()`, `corARMA()`, and `corCAR1()` for AR(1), ARMA and continuous time AR(1) serial correlations.

Answer (score 0):

AUTOBOX is a program that I am familiar with having written both of these modules for AFS a company that I am still working with. The distinguishing features of AUTOBOX is that it can automatically determine the weights required for GLS while automatically identifying the ARIMA structure. They have a 30 day free demo at http://www.autobox.com/30day.exe . If you have any questions about the output you can deal with them directly.